# Как генерировать объекты за экраном с заданным промежутком

Tags: spritekit, xcode, разработка-игр, objective-c, ios7

Приветствую всех! Делаю игру на spritekit с бесконечным уровнем (like Doodle jump)и возникла проблема:
Не могу понять как генерировать платформы за экраном так, чтобы новые генерировались только после того, как предыдущая платформа уехала на определенное расстояние?
Вот пример кода для генирации платформ

```
- (void)addPlatforms
{
    int random = arc4random() % (int)(self.frame.size.width-80)+100;

    // right end platform
    SKSpriteNode *rightEndPlatform = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"leftPlatform"];
    rightEndPlatform.size = CGSizeMake(16, 16);
    rightEndPlatform.physicsBody =
    [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(rightEndPlatform.size.width, rightEndPlatform.size.height - 5)];
    rightEndPlatform.position = CGPointMake(random, 0);

    // left end platform
    SKSpriteNode *leftEndPlatform = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"rightPlatform"];
    leftEndPlatform.size = CGSizeMake(16, 16);
    leftEndPlatform.physicsBody =
    [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(leftEndPlatform.size.width, leftEndPlatform.size.height - 5)];
    leftEndPlatform.position = CGPointMake(rightEndPlatform.position.x - PLATFORM_RANGE, rightEndPlatform.position.y);

    // left platform
    SKSpriteNode *leftPlatform = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"centerPlatform"];
    leftPlatform.size = CGSizeMake(leftEndPlatform.position.x, 16);
    leftPlatform.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:leftPlatform.frame.size];
    leftPlatform.position =
    CGPointMake(leftEndPlatform.position.x - leftPlatform.size.width/2,
                leftEndPlatform.position.y);

    // right platform
    SKSpriteNode *rightPlatform = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"centerPlatform"];
    rightPlatform.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width+rightEndPlatform.position.x, 16);
    rightPlatform.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:rightPlatform.frame.size];
    rightPlatform.position =
    CGPointMake(rightEndPlatform.position.x + rightPlatform.size.width/2,
                rightEndPlatform.position.y);

    // add to the scene
    [self addChild:rightEndPlatform];
    [self addChild:leftEndPlatform];
    [self addChild:leftPlatform];
    [self addChild:rightPlatform];

    // add platforms to array
    [platformArray addObject:rightEndPlatform];
    [platformArray addObject:leftEndPlatform];
    [platformArray addObject:leftPlatform];
    [platformArray addObject:rightPlatform];

    for (int i = 0; i < [platformArray count]; i++)
    {
        SKSpriteNode *sprite = [platformArray objectAtIndex:i];
        sprite.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
        sprite.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
        sprite.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"beforePlayer"];
    }
}
```

Генерирую платформу, потом напротив через промежуток другую платформу и достраиваю от краев экрана до этих платформ линии, получая стенку с проходом.
Далее двигаю созданную конструкцию

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [platformArray count]; i++)
    {
        SKSpriteNode *platform = [platformArray objectAtIndex:i];
        platform.position = CGPointMake(platform.position.x, platform.position.y + PLATFORM_SPEED);
        if (platform.position.y > self.frame.size.height+100)
        {
            [platform removeFromParent];
        }
    }
}
```

а генерация платформ происходит по времени

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:TIME_INTERVAL target:self selector:@selector(addPlatforms) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Вот и вопрос, вообще правильно ли я делаю или есть лучше вариант, как генерировать платформы не по времени а по расстоянию (первая сгенерированная платформа уехала на 100 единиц , тогда генерируем вторую, вторая уехала на 100 единиц- генерируем третью и т.д)
Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: Никто не может помочь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сразу прошу прощения, не стал вчитываться в код, (как известно, разбирать чужой код это, как лезть кому-то в душу) ). Наиболее изящный, по моему скромному мнению, выход из этой ситуации таков:

1) Остановите движение платформ, временно закомментировав соответствующую часть кода в update

2) На неподвижном экране создайте максимально возможное число платформ (на нужном Вам расстоянии друг от друга). Это легко сделать, с помощью цикла for.

3) Сдвиньте точку генерации первой из платформ на нужное расстояние за экраном.

4) Далее, в методе update начинайте двигать платформы (кстати, доступ к платформе можно получить, присвоив ей имя (если не знаете как, я напишу)) и, при этом, как только платформа пройдет нужное расстояние (то, что между каждой из платформ) за экран, Вам необходимо переместить ее в начальную точку (в ту, в которой происходила генерация первой платформы).

При выполнении данного алгоритма у Вас получится непрерывный "поток" платформ, причем без наложений  и дополнительной генирации (то макимальное число платформ вы просто перемещаете "по кругу")

Надеюсь, у меня получилось донести до Вас мысль об общем построении таких конструкций.

Если нужно что-то описать подробней, пишите, не стесняйтесь.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый комментарий,но проблема еще в том что за экраном генерируются две платформы с промежутком между ними,находящемся в рандомном месте каждый раз, если не совсем корректно объяснил- есть игра,называется happy poo fall,интересует такая генерация платформ:-)